# List#() on Intermediate List

Tags: scala

I can get the `index = 2` item from a `List` using [apply](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List).

```
scala> List(1,2,3).apply(2)
res3: Int = 3

scala> val x = List(1,2,3)
x: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> x(2)
res4: Int = 3

scala> List(1,2,3).apply(2)
res5: Int = 3
```

But, why can't I do the following?

```
scala> List(1,2,3).(2)
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but '(' found.
       List(1,2,3).(2)
                   ^
```

Comment: Definitely not one of my best questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't need `.`

```
scala> List(1,2,3)(2)
res1: Int = 3
```